# Is there an alternative way to pass data to another activity without using the intent

Tags: android

I am writing a library that takes a user from his present activity to another, then return the users back to the initial activity but also with a payload/data. Presently I use an intent to perform this, but it seems unprofessional. I want to know if android has an alternative like how ios or react-native has Notification or dispatchers that emit to notifications to listeners.

Comment: THe only way to launch a new Activity is an Intent.  If you want an Intent to return a result, the correct way is to use startActivityForResult, and then return a result Intent in the child Activity which will be passed to the onActivityResult function of the launching Activity

Comment: "Presently I use an intent to perform this, but it seems unprofessional" -- why? "I want to know if android has an alternative like how ios or react-native has Notification or dispatchers that emit to notifications to listeners" -- not for between activities. Perhaps you should not have used an activity as your primary unit of UI. Had you used a fragment, you would have many more communication options.

Comment: @CommonsWare yeah I feel I should  not have used and activity, I modal would have sufficied.

Comment: you can define static your object and then you can call